# How to convert python log normal distribution code to c++ code

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost, probability

I have a python code to calculate the probability using lognormal distribution function and want to convert it to c++. I tried the boost library but it does not provide the required functionality (as per my findings, please correct me if I am wrong).

```py
df['prob'] = (1 - scipy.stats.lognorm(s=sd, loc=0, scale=math.exp(mean)).cdf(df.cum_size))**exponent
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: you should show your c++ code not the python code.

Comment: You can't do the same with https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/include/boost/math/distributions/lognormal.hpp?

Comment: @user14717 Yeah can do that but how that additional `loc` parameter which is passed in scipy.lognorm can be done in boost?